# How to set the GCM user regstration?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-cloud-messaging

In my app I have already a registration page with the details that my app needs. I'm following this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/ and it said here that I need to make a registration page that the user will fill there has full name and an email. is it necessary? Can someone explain me why the user needs to fill has email? How can I merge it with my registration page?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't **need** an e-mail or anything other than the regId in order to send a GCM to particular application on a particular device. What is **convenient** is to have a  one to one mapping between say the device owner/project combination and a regID stored in your server's database. So it's really up to you what you decide to use as a unique key.